# BIOS wont recognize bootloader

Tags: linux, boot, arch-linux, bootloader

I have been using systemd-boot as a bootloader for the last year and a half, with dual boot between windows and arch linux.
It was all working fine until I cloned my old (sata m.2)ssd into a new one(NVME m.2), now BIOS boots directly into windows instead of systemd-boot because it doesn't seem to recognize it, it doesn't show as an option in boot order.

This issue happens with both the new drive (after cloning) and the old one.
I CAN boot into systemd-boot if I chose the option "boot with file" on the bios and select the file "/boot/efi/Bootbootx64.efi", but not even after doing that the BIOS recognized it.

How could I fix this issue?

```
Laptop model: HP Elitebook 840 G5
SSD model: Kingston SN550
```

Comment: See [Installing the EFI boot manager](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Systemd-boot#Installing_the_EFI_boot_manager). If this helps I'll put up an answer.

Comment: Thanks, it was solved by running bootctl update, feel free to post your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems with the EFI boot manager after cloning may require it to
reinstalled.

See the Arch Linux article
[Installing the EFI boot manager](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Systemd-boot#Installing_the_EFI_boot_manager)
for a detailed discussion on how to install and configure the
the EFI boot manager.

For the poster, it was enough to run :

```
bootctl update
```

This command is described in the above article in section
"1.3 Updating the EFI boot manager" subsection "1.3.1 Manual update":

> Whenever there is a new version of systemd-boot, the EFI boot manager can be optionally reinstalled by the user.